# Is there a way to iterate over a slice in reverse in Go?

Tags: go

It would be convenient to be able to say something like:

```
for _, element := reverse range mySlice {
        ...
}
```

*Edit*: I asked this question a long time ago, it *is* 2022 now and the generic solution by @Ivan below seems like the way to go!

Answer (score 224, accepted):

No there is no convenient operator for this to add to the range one in place. You'll have to do a normal `for` loop counting down:

```
s := []int{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
for i := len(s)-1; i >= 0; i-- {
   fmt.Println(s[i])
}
```

Comment: The [effective go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) page an example, but this one is actually a bit nicer and declares fewer variables.

Comment: IMO Go desperately needs a descending range construct. Not having it causes a good deal of extra work, as we can see.... –

Comment: I wouldn't say desperately, it would be a nice have.

Comment: A language shortcoming that forces you to use indices to access elements of an array, for a super common use case, when a solution is easily achievable, is in desperate need of that solution.

Comment: I can't tell which is worse, that Go doesn't know how to iterate over an array backwards or that people think that's fine. This language is like 30% complete.

Answer (score 62):

You can also do:

```
s := []int{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
for i := range s {
        fmt.Println(s[len(s)-1-i]) // Suggestion: do `last := len(s)-1` before the loop
}
```

---

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Also here: http://play.golang.org/p/l7Z69TV7Vl

Answer (score 21):

Variation with index

```
for k := range s {
        k = len(s) - 1 - k
        // now k starts from the end
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

One could use a channel to reverse a list in a function without duplicating it.  It makes the code nicer in my sense.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func reverse(lst []string) chan string {
    ret := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for i, _ := range lst {
            ret <- lst[len(lst)-1-i]
        }
        close(ret)
    }()
    return ret
}

func main() {
    elms := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
    for e := range reverse(elms) {
        fmt.Println(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like a clean and nice-to-use solution to me. Is it possible to generalize this using the type `[]interface{}`? Because the present `reverse`-function only supports strings.

Comment: For sure, just replace string by interface{} and you are good to Go.  I just want to stress that a function with signature `func reverse(lst []interface{}) chan inyterface{} ` will not take a []string as input anymore.  Even if string can be casted in interface{}, []string cannot be casted in []interface{}.  Unfortunately, the present reverse function is the kind of function that needs to be rewritten a lot.

Comment: Thank you. That's the ugly part of go I think - which is somehow unavoidable. Thank you!

Comment: I would implement a stack rather than this.

Comment: This would be especially nice embedded in a type that had these semantics.

Comment: Clever - but creating a goroutine to do a simple reverse op is overkill.

Comment: Channels should be used to communicate between goroutines. Not for simple string reverse functions. Super overkill.

Comment: @Atmocreations: you can use `func reverse[T any](lst []T) chan T {...}`

Answer (score 5):

How about use defer:

```
s := []int{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
for i, _ := range s {
   defer fmt.Println(s[i])
}
```

Comment: Was going to down-vote but checked and... How the hell it works? I guess it cant be guaranteed to be executed in exactly this reverse order. I've asked a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073538/go-why-defer-in-range-loop-is-called-in-a-reverse-order

Comment: I've up-voted just for the fact it brought some new knowledge about `defer` but I believe using this inside a loop for reverse is quite tricky and should be pretty ineffective memory-wise.

Comment: It "works", but if the loop isn't the last thing in the function you may get unexpected results. [Example.](https://play.golang.org/p/PxzTU0s1zw)

Comment: This is using `defer` in a way that it is not intended for. Don't use this since it can have nasty side effects (out of order execution). Just use the `for` loop in the accepted answer. Go is aiming to minimize this kind of *clever* (not) hacks since they tend to bite you in the ass later on.

Comment: This is a hacky use of defer and should be avoided. If this is, for example, a function which someone might extend in future, it may have unintended consequences.

Comment: This wasn't quite 'iffy' enough, so I went ahead and *added* channels https://play.golang.org/p/GodEiv1LlIJ

Comment: @Xeoncross What's funny is... channels are quite similar to iterators in other languages, and this is similar to how they accomplish a reverse iterator!

Answer (score 5):

In 2022, you could use generics to reverse any slice in-place:

```
func reverse[S ~[]E, E any](s S) {
    for i, j := 0, len(s)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, except that this is not at all what the question is asking.

Comment: If you want to reverse the slice with Go 1.21 (released August 2023) you have the slices.Reverse (you need to import slices) that reverses the elements of the slice in place.
So in order to iterate in reverse order you need first to slice.Reverse(mySlice) and then use a regular For or For-each range.

Answer (score -2):

When I need to extract elements from a slice and reverse range, I use something like this code:

```
// reverse range
// Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/gx6fJIfb7fo
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Elem struct {
    Id   int64
    Name string
}

type Elems []Elem

func main() {
    mySlice := Elems{{Id: 0, Name: "Alice"}, {Id: 1, Name: "Bob"}, {Id: 2, Name: "Carol"}}
    for i, element := range mySlice {
        fmt.Printf("Normal  range: [%v] %+v\n", i, element)
    }

    //mySlice = Elems{}
    //mySlice = Elems{{Id: 0, Name: "Alice"}}
    if last := len(mySlice) - 1; last >= 0 {
        for i, element := last, mySlice[0]; i >= 0; i-- {
            element = mySlice[i]
            fmt.Printf("Reverse range: [%v] %+v\n", i, element)
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println("mySlice empty")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Normal  range: [0] {Id:0 Name:Alice}
Normal  range: [1] {Id:1 Name:Bob}
Normal  range: [2] {Id:2 Name:Carol}
Reverse range: [2] {Id:2 Name:Carol}
Reverse range: [1] {Id:1 Name:Bob}
Reverse range: [0] {Id:0 Name:Alice}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/gx6fJIfb7fo

Answer (score -4):

You can use the [`funk.ForEachRight`](https://github.com/thoas/go-funk#funkforeachright) method from [go-funk](https://github.com/thoas/go-funk):

```golang
results := []int{}

funk.ForEachRight([]int{1, 2, 3, 4}, func(x int) {
    results = append(results, x)
})

fmt.Println(results) // []int{4, 3, 2, 1}
```