# Why defer in range loop is called in a reverse order?

Tags: go

I've run across an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190836/is-there-a-way-to-iterate-over-a-slice-in-reverse-in-go/35471657#35471657) on a question about "reverse range" and I was going to down-vote it as it seemed ridiculously wrong but checked and it actually works(!):

https://play.golang.org/p/4K2fDlSoCm

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    for i, _ := range s {
        defer fmt.Println(s[i])
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
5
4
3
2
1
Program exited.
```

Any ideas why it works this way? Am I right it's not guaranteed to be executed exactly in the reverse order? Also I don't think it's a good way to write programs but curious to find why are we getting this result.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`defer` is a `LIFO`, or a stack - it is guaranteed to executed in reverse order. It gets the first `defer` and puts it on some internal stack (probably, I don't know the gory details), and then puts the next `defer` on top of that one, and then when it hits the end of the function, it unwinds, starting at the top. It seems contrived in a `for`-loop (I know this is Go's example, not yours), but in other cases where one function depends upon the clean-up of some other function, it makes more sense why it SHOULD be, and hence IS, guaranteed to be reverse order of execution.

Here's a different example, all pseudo-code, but hopefully the point is clear.

```
open stream1
defer close stream1
defer write stream1 "stream2 better be closed, or we are in trouble..."
open stream2
defer close stream2
defer stream2 "this is the last you'll ever hear from stream2"

connect stream2 to stream1

write stream2 "hey, we are in stream2, this feeds into stream1"
```

Should print something like:

```
"hey, we are in stream2, this feeds into stream1"
"this is the last you'll ever hear from stream2"
"stream2 better be closed, or we are in trouble..."
```

If you didn't have guarantees about reverse ordering, you couldn't be sure `stream1` was still open during your `defer stream2 write`.

Comment: Thanks, it totally make sense now. But using inside a loop for reverse is quite tricky and should be pretty ineffective memory-wise.

Comment: Yeah, I remember not being thrilled with that play.golang example, because it's so contrived as to be confusing, and it didn't really get at why it ought to be reverse. Glad I could help!